# Operator overloading+ add two objects

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm trying to add two object that they are in the same class.

In the private section of the class I have two `int` variables

```
class One {

private:
int num1, num2;
public:

    One operator+=(const One&); // - a member operator that adds another One object - to the current object and returns a copy of the current object
    friend bool operator==(const One&, const One&); // - a friend operator that compares two One class objects for equality
};

 One operator+(const One&, const One&);// - a non-friend helper operator that adds One objects without changing their values and returns a copy of the resulting One
```

I'm not sure I have a problem on the `opeartor+` I guess

```
One operator+(const One &a, const One &b){

One c,d,r;

c = a;
d = b;

r += b;
r += a;

return r;
}
```

I think the above code is wrong, but I tried to use like b.num1 and I get compile error

`error: 'int One::num1' is private
error: within this context`

and I can't use b->num1 as well because the above function is not in the member function section.

```
error: base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'const One'
```

This is how it calls in `main`

`Result = LeftObject + RightObject;`

Comment: Whe the `operator+` is wrong ? BTW: you forget to initialize the members.

Comment: You cant do `b.num1`, `num1` is a private member. If you need to access it you need to have a *getter* function for that. `b->` is invalid as you have not created a pointer type. Do you intended to add the private integers?

Comment: @another.anon.coward how can I get that? I just want to find a way to do a copy of two objects and then return them in object's name `r`

Comment: I am not sorry, I dont quite understand. What should `operator +` add? To get private create a public function which returns the private member maybe - `public:  inline int getInt1(){return int1;}`

Comment: @another.anon.coward in the `operator+` it suppose to add two objects together and assign it to object call `r` then return that to the main function in main the calling of this operator is like this

`Result = Left + right;`

Comment: What is the *addition* operation for your object? It depends on how you define addition, for eg `operator +` for `string` object concatenates the contents

Comment: Please post the code that is responsible for the first error message.

Comment: @another.anon.coward they both have `num1` and `num2` so what happen I'm suppose to add them up and do some modification in another function, but I can't even access them since this function isn't a member nor friend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have already implemented this member function:

```
One One::operator+=(const One&);
```

Then you may implement the non-member addition operator thus:

```
One operator+(const One& lhs, const One& rhs) {
  One result = lhs;
  result += rhs;
  return result;
}
```

This can be simplified somewhat into the following:

```
One operator+(One lhs, const One& rhs) {
  return lhs += rhs;
}
```

This pattern (which you can adapt for all operator/operator-assignment pairs) declares the operator-assignment version as a member -- it can access the private members. It declares the operator version as a non-friend non-member -- this allows type promotion on either side of the operator.

*Aside*: The `+=` method should return a reference to `*this`, not a copy. So its declaration should be: `One& operator+(const One&)`.

---

**EDIT**: A working sample program follows.

```
#include <iostream>
class One {
private:
  int num1, num2;

public:
  One(int num1, int num2) : num1(num1), num2(num2) {}
  One& operator += (const One&);
  friend bool operator==(const One&, const One&);
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const One&);
};

std::ostream&
operator<<(std::ostream& os, const One& rhs) {
  return os << "(" << rhs.num1 << "@" << rhs.num2 << ")";
}

One& One::operator+=(const One& rhs) {
  num1 += rhs.num1;
  num2 += rhs.num2;
  return *this;
}

One operator+(One lhs, const One &rhs)
{
  return lhs+=rhs;
}

int main () {
  One x(1,2), z(3,4);
  std::cout << x << " + " << z << " => " << (x+z) << "\n";
}
```

Comment: I don't think you should modify the lhs

Comment: I don't. In both instances I modify a *local copy* of the lhs. In the first instance, I make the copy explicitly. In the second instance, I ask the compiler to make a copy (because `lhs` is passed by value, not passed by reference.)

Comment: It works, but my result still wrong, probably my another function is not complete.

Comment: The operator I list depends upon a working copy constructor and a working `operator +=`. Yes, if either of those are incorrect, the result will be incorrect.

Comment: @Ali - I've included a sample program that might help you.

Comment: @Robᵩ your `operator+=` looks great! I think I have to implement something on my function to make it work correctly.

Comment: @Ali - clearly your `operator+=` may be different (for example, you might be adding rational numbers or complex numbers, or have some other domain-specific algorithm), **but** your `operator+` can be identical to mine. Since `operator+=` holds all of the knowledge, `operator+` can be completely boilerplate!

Comment: @Robᵩ should I ask in another question or in this same post?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13122/discussion-between-rob-and-ali)

Answer (score 1):

I can't see why the `operator+` is wrong:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class One {
    public:
        One(int n1, int n2): num1(n1),num2(n2) {}

    private:
        int num1, num2;
    public:
        One operator+=(const One& o) {
            num1 += o.num1;
            num2 += o.num2;
            return *this;
        }
        friend bool operator==(const One&, const One&); // - a friend operator that compares two One class objects for equality
        void print() {
            printf("%d,%d\n", num1, num2);
        }
};

One operator+(const One& a, const One& b) {
    One r(0,0);
    r += b;
    r += a;
    return r;
}

int main() {
    One a(1,2),b(3,4);
    One r = a + b;
    r.print();
}
```

Comment: It's usual to copy one argument and then add the other to it (i.e. `One r=a; r+=b;`). That will work even if the type doesn't have an additive identity.

Comment: `#include <cstdio>` maybe? :)